# Refire the jQuery ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery `$(document).ready()` event on page. All is fine, except that
if I am loading data using Ajax calls, the `$(document).ready()` event does not fire. I guess that it behave in such way because the page was already loaded and I am just adding more data from the Ajax response to the DOM.

How can I refire the `ready` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute some additionnal Javascript, you might use a function that you call upon Ajax callback onComplete event :

```
function initJS(){
    //your code here
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data){
  },
  complete: function(){
        initJS();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

.load(), .bind(), or .live() will be your friends here....

Answer (score 0):

just break the logic that is in the "$(document).ready( function() {});" block out into a separate function. Then the page will call it once when it is "ready", and you can directly call that function when you want to do a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the person asking is because most developer doing jQuery plugins i.e wordpress plugins use the "ready" function.

Everyone here is saying go modify the plugins !

I'm facing the same problem as I'm developing AJAX template for wp and most plugins don't work !